# В матрице на боковой диагонали найти максимум

Tags: python, python-3.x

В матрице найти максимальный элемент на боковой диагонали. Что-то не получилось. Как поправить?

```
n=int(input("N:"))
a=[]

for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        a[i].append(int(input("input element:")))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(a[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j==(n-1)-i:
            b=[max(a[j])]
result=max(b)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы негде не сохраняете значение `b`, сделайте так:

```
b = [] 
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j==(n-1)-i:
            b.append(a[j][i]) 
result=max(b)
```

Comment: спасибо большое